# std::chrono time_t conversions overflow?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

My Sample Code:

```
time_t time_tee = 253402210800;
auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time_tee);
time_t tee2 = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
std::cout << tee2 << std::endl;
```

Expectation: Output of 2534022108
Output: -4852206231

time_t is 64bit, so there should not be an overflow.

What kind of overflow am I triggering here?

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EenLbz)
[Works fine on MSVC](https://rextester.com/QSPR47297)

Comment: Just to confirm, what do you get outputted for `std::cout << time_tee << std::endl;`?

Comment: `12/30/9999` is probably out of range of the values representable by `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` on your platform

Comment: @AlanBirtles That seems to be the case for [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e89173483a77fd8) as well (which claims to be on Ubuntu). ;-)

Comment: If my system was out of spec, I would have expected a compiler warning. e.g. on 32bit systems I get: 
```warning: implicit conversion from 'long long' to 'time_t' (aka 'int') changes value from 253402210800 to -859664 [-Wconstant-conversion]
```

Comment: That would only apply for assigning a constant to a smaller type, as there are calculations in between the compiler doesn't realise the values are out of range

Comment: What is `std::chrono::system_clock::rep` on your system?

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same<time_t, long>::value == true);`. `time_t` could be 64-bit and could be `unsigned`. But is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`glibc` `system_clock::duration`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L888) uses `chrono::nanoseconds` to store the time point. [`chrono::nanoseconds`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L651) is `int64_t`.

Because:

```
253402210800 seconds = 253402210800000000000 nanoseconds
INT64_MAX            = 922337203685477580
```

the computation overflows on glibc.

I don't see any constraints on `system_clock::rep` in [the standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system) except that it should be signed.

> What kind of overflow am I triggering here?

Signed overflow happens inside `system_clock::from_time_t(time_tee);` when `253402210800` is multiplied by `1000000000` when casting `time_t` to `system_clock::duration` inside `time_point_cast<system_clock::duration>`. I think that would be exactly inside [`__duration_cast_impl`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L150).

I think you should protect against overflow with a check, for example:

```
static_assert(
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
    (std::chrono::system_clock::duration::max()).count() > 253402210800
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is time resolution of `system_clock`.

This code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::chrono::system_clock;
    time_t time_tee = 253402210800;
    auto tp = system_clock::from_time_t(time_tee);
    time_t tee2 = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    std::cout << time_tee << std::endl;
    std::cout << tee2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << system_clock::period::num << std::endl;
    std::cout << system_clock::period::den << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On [MSVC prints](https://rextester.com/BZBQ85923):

```
253402210800
253402210800
1
10000000
```

On [GCC or clang prints](https://godbolt.org/z/Erades):

```
253402210800
-4852206231
1
1000000000
```

So as you can see GCC and Clang are using `system_cloc` 100 times bigger resolution. Note that this is also resolution better then `time_t` offers and cost is more limited time range.